# Single-phase thyristor full bridge rectifier vs three-phase thyristor full bridge rectifier

Tags: three-phase, harmonics, thyristor, single-phase, full-bridge

For Single-phase thyristor full bridge rectifier compared to a three-phase thyristor full bridge rectifier, with regards the input current harmonics, does the three- phase rectifier have an advantage over the single phase rectifier?[image: three-phase]
[image: single-phase]

Comment: Schematics please. Have you tried simulating?

Comment: Yes it does ,.   .

Comment: i was looking like in greater detail why.

Comment: What may override this question is the need for power factor correcting and, with the three phase system shown, you cannot do this anywhere near as effectively as three single phase systems.